# Save the file in C#

Tags: c#

I have a tree view and a button and a toolbox. I will create the tree by dragging and dropping items from toolbox. At the end, i will store the tree structure as an xml file. For this, when I click on the button, it prompts for save dialog and once the user select the path to store, I am able to save the xml file successfully. Now, if I want to save the structure without opening the save dialog every time(whenever I make changes to tree structure) when I make changes(except first time) like in MS word, how can I achieve it?

Comment: Do you want all the code, so you dont have to think or write a single bit of it?

Comment: What kind of app is this?

Answer (score 0):

Just save the file name you chose in the dialog in a variable. Next time check if you have the file name, if you do simply save the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are "dragging and dropping" the SaveFileDialog on your form, the SaveFileDialog object will have the FileName set until you close the application. There is no need to save to a field in your forms class. Though it is basically the same.

```
    private SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = null;

    private string GetFileName()
    {
        if (saveFileDialog.FileName != String.IsNullOrEmpty(saveFileDialog.FileName))
        {
            return saveFileDialog.FileName;
        }
        else
        {
            if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                return saveFileDialog.FileName;
            }
            else
            {
                //throw exception or something similar
            }
        }
    }
```